# Nodejs: Error: certificate signature failure

Tags: node.js, tls1.2

we get a `Error: certificate signature failure` when we try to establish TLS connection to a server. The server is running openldap in our case. How can we debug this?

Our client code is [here](https://gist.github.com/siddjain/15051c45b9d447fb4f7f0c0a9caa5279)

Server logs are [here](https://gist.github.com/siddjain/5613f6d0ed5cde2f39b9ff8542c33ce8)

Code output is

```
Client error { Error: certificate signature failure
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1116:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:643:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:473:38) code: 'CERT_SIGNATURE_FAILURE' }
```

we checked the certificate signature is OK

```
root@fcaf052d50fc:/container/service/slapd/assets/certs# openssl verify -CAfile jnj-ca-chain.pem jnj-ldap-server-tls.pem
jnj-ldap-server-tls.pem: OK
```

In debugger we have been able to step through the code until _tls_wrap.js Line 1116:

```
var verifyError = socket._handle.verifyError();
```

[image]

which is where it fails and we can't step into above method. Doing some search brought [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/node_crypto.cc#L2529)

tcpdump shows that we seem to be getting expected certificate from the server:

[image]

so this is extremely strange:

1. openssl verify passes
2. client seems to be getting cert from server .
3. but nodejs verification fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we debugged this using

```
$ openssl s_client -connect localhost:636 -state -nbio -CAfile jnj-ca-chain.pem -showcerts
```

which showed that the TLS certificate returned to the client was different from the one provided to the server (likely a bug in GnuTLS [[1]](https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap/issues/315))